# Was the caucus race filmed for the 1985 Alice in Wonderland miniseries?

Tags: tv, adaptations, alice-in-wonderland

In December 1985, [CBS broadcast a two-night miniseries version of *Alice in Wonderland*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088693/), produced by Irwin Allen.  I remember watching it at the time (although not live; it was actually the first program my family recorded with our new VCR).  In total, it was three hours long, and I liked that it included both *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* and *Through the Looking Glass*, with their separate (although eventually overlapping) casts of characters.  To fill out those casts Allen cast many famous stars in small-to-medium-sized parts.

As a child, I didn't recognize most of the celebrities who made appearances (although several of them, such as Carol Channing, I did know from watching *The Muppet Show*).  So I wasn't particularly surprised that some of the roles were very small.  However, watching it again as an adult, I noticed that some of those very small roles went to rather prominent actors.  In particular, after miniaturized Alice falls into the stream of her own tears, she meets several other wet creatures, including a mouse (played by Sherman Hemsley) whom she befriends and who sings her a song.

However, among the birds who also get caught in the tears are two played by Donald O'Connor (the Lory Bird) and Shelley Winters (the Dodo)—rather prominent actors who get starring billing at the opening, in spite of having at most a handful of lines.  It seems that their roles were mostly cut, and this is confirmed by the series credits, which list [Miriam Nelson](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0291505/) as choreographer for "The Caucus Race," "I Hate Dogs and Cats," "Off With Their Heads," "There's Something to Say for Hatred," "The Royal Procession," and "I Didn't, You Did."  However, the caucus race, in which the wet creatures run in circles around a rock outcropping to dry off, under the supervision of the Dodo, does not appear in the show.  It looks like the set was built for it; Alice does end up standing on a stone while the animals run circles around her, but it is part of the dance that goes with Hemsley's song, "I Hate Dogs and Cats."

This therefore all leaves me wondering:  Was the caucus race dance actually filmed?  And, if so, is the footage conceivably available anywhere?

Comment: I guess the broader question is, are any of the outtakes still extant?